# Only one word in println is shown and the rest do not

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I type a phrase into the console, only one word appears below the green text while the other words do not appear. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a sentence or phrase. It can be anything you want it to be: ");

//ask user for sentence or phrase
String p1 = keyboard.next(); 

System.out.println(c1); //display user sentence or phrase
```

Comment: Scanner.next() stops at whitespace. Scanner.nextLine() to read until '\n'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) reads a *single word*<sup>1</sup>, use [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to read the entire line.

---

<sup>1</sup> Specifically, `next()` "Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern". The default delimiter is `\s+`, a continuous string of whitespace characters. You can change this delimiter via [`useDelimiter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a sentence or phrase. It can be anything you want it to be: ");

//ask user for sentence or phrase
String p1 = keyboard.nextLine(); 

System.out.println(c1); //display user sentence or phrase
```

The problem is

```
keyboard.next();
```

only gets a single word. You need to use:

```
keyboard.nextLine();
```